# Date Culture issues in remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, cultureinfo

Im coding an ASP.NET MVC app on a spanish machine, so my date is (dd/mm/yyyy).

But my remote vps use an en-US W2k8 so when I create a date in that machine it will be (mm/dd/yyyy)

Im not sure what is the correct way to resolve that.

I have a register form that take a string of type (dd/mm/yyyy) and send it to the controller. I guess that the model binder create a new DateTime that will be sent to the controller because if I insert (on remote) something like 31/10/2011 it says that the date is not correct, so when the model binder try to create the DateTime it cry.

So I need a way to specify (I guess that will be something global) that all my dates will be dd/mm/yyyy. So when the model binder create a new date, it will use that format.

How I do that? I think that it will be problematic on a future because I want to localize my app on english too and the english users will use mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have any experience with MVC3, but on a high level your problem is pretty trivial.
Your current thread culture needs to match the one on the client side before request is bound to the model object. There are different ways to do it, but most obvious are:

1) split application into top level culture subfolders. I.e. turn your /my_url/ into /en/my_url/, /sp/my_url/ etc. Throw a Web.config into each with relevant culture setting.
This is probably more work than you care to put into it.

2) post culture info with the form data and intercept it before binding. I am sure there is some kind of event you can handle before your controller action is executed. You can throw there a 1-liner to set the current thread culture depending on the post parameter.

There is probably a way to combine these two based on request mapping. Something along the lines of /{language}/my_url/. Like I said I don't really use MS version of the MVC design pattern enough to know the technical details of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the culture in the web config file